# how to get list of wired LAN connections ignoring Wifi (wireless) LAN connection in C#

Tags: .net, wifi, lan

in C#, I want to get list of wired LAN connection of my laptop at runtime, but I do not want any wifi or wireless LAN.

I have used various ways to get network list :-

`ManagementClass`:

```
ManagementClass objMC = new ManagementClass("Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration");
 ManagementObjectCollection objMOC = objMC.GetInstances();

 foreach (ManagementObject objMO in objMOC)
        {
            if (!(bool)objMO["ipEnabled"])
                continue;
           this.textBox1.Text += (Convert.ToString(objMO["Description"])) + Environment.NewLine;
        }
```

Above code gives no information about type of network (wifi or wired)

`NetworkInterface` class:

```
foreach (NetworkInterface nic in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces())

        {
            this.textBox1.Text += nic.Name.ToString();    

            this.textBox1.Text += "MAC: " + nic.GetPhysicalAddress().ToString();

            this.textBox1.Text += "Type: " + nic.NetworkInterfaceType;
            this.textBox1.Text += "Description: " + nic.Description.ToString();
            this.textBox1.Text += "OperationalStatus: " + nic.OperationalStatus.ToString() + ;
        }
```

Above code gives me list of Ethernet LAN description.
even NetworkInterfaceType for wifi LAN is showing as Ehternet, e.g:
   Type: Ethernet
   Description: Intel(R) Centrino(R) Ultimate-N 6300 AGN - Packet Scheduler Miniport

I mean there no way to differentiate which one is wireless or wired network.

I have also tried **`NativeWifi.WlanClient`**, but it crashes.

```
  Wlan.WlanAvailableNetwork[] networks = wlanIface.GetAvailableNetworkList(0);
        foreach (Wlan.WlanAvailableNetwork network in networks)
        {   
            if (network.dot11DefaultCipherAlgorithm == Wlan.Dot11CipherAlgorithm.WEP)
            {
                this.textBox1.Text = string.Format("Found WEP network with SSID {0}: ", GetStringForSSID(network.dot11Ssid)) + Environment.NewLine;
            }
        }
```

Any guidance will be appreciated. 
Thanks

Comment: Is it possible in ASP.NET ? how to get client side available wifi networks?

Answer (score 5):

```
NetworkInterface[] nics=NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();

foreach(NetworkInterface adapter in nics)
{
  if(adapter.OperationalStatus==OperationalStatus.Up)
  {
    if(adapter.NetworkInterfaceType==NetworkInterfaceType.Wireless80211)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Wifi");
    }
    else
    {
      Console.WriteLine("do your work");
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**This will eliminate all interfaces otherthan physical wired interfaces**

```csharp
    NetworkInterface[] networkInterfaces = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();
                                        foreach (var networkInterface in networkInterfaces)
                                        {
                                            
                                            if (networkInterface.NetworkInterfaceType != NetworkInterfaceType.Loopback &&
                                            networkInterface.NetworkInterfaceType != NetworkInterfaceType.Wwanpp &&
                                            networkInterface.NetworkInterfaceType != NetworkInterfaceType.Wwanpp2 &&
                                            networkInterface.NetworkInterfaceType != NetworkInterfaceType.Wireless80211 &&
                                            networkInterface.NetworkInterfaceType != NetworkInterfaceType.Unknown &&
                                            networkInterface.NetworkInterfaceType != NetworkInterfaceType.HighPerformanceSerialBus &&
                                            networkInterface.NetworkInterfaceType != NetworkInterfaceType.Slip &&
                                            networkInterface.NetworkInterfaceType != NetworkInterfaceType.Tunnel && 
                                            networkInterface.OperationalStatus != OperationalStatus.NotPresent && 
                                            !networkInterface.Name.Contains("Bluetooth") && !networkInterface.Description.Contains("Virtual"))
                                            {
                                                Trace.Write($"Description :{networkInterface.Description}");
                                                Trace.WriteLine($"Interface Name: {networkInterface.Name}");
                
                
                                            }
                                        }
```